# Find the atractor of the triangles formed by joining the feet of altitudes of the previous triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles

Triangle 1 (see the picture) is given. Find the point toward which the vertices of triangle n -> infinity converge, assuming that triangle n is constructed by uniting the feet of the altitudes of triangle n-1.

[image]
Sequence of triangles formed by the above mentioned rule.

For the definition of "foot of an altitude" please see: [Perpendicular Foot](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerpendicularFoot.html)

Comment: Can you explain, perhaps in a separate paragraph from the _question_, the rule for constructing additional triangles? An algorithm for triangle $n$, in terms on $n-1$, would fine. Basically I have no idea what you mean by "uniting the feet of the altitudes".

Comment: @ShapeOfMatter: I believe it is quite clear: if $T_n$ is the triangle at the $n$-th step, $T_{n+1}$ is the orthic triangle of $T_{n}$.

Answer (score 6):

By denoting as $T_n$ the triangle at the $n$-th iteration we can easily describe the angles of $T_{n+1}$, orthic triangle of $T_n$, in terms of the angles of $T_n$. We may check that the area and the perimeter of $T_n$ converge to zero, but the "shape" of $T_n$  (i.e. the triple of the angles) does not converge, in the general case.
Actually [it is known](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225463670_The_Chaotic_Behavior_of_the_Sequence_of_Pedal_Simplices) that such iteration is usually chaotic, and not difficult to prove: assuming that our sequence is convergent to a point $P$, from some $n$ onward the orthocenter of $T_n$ has to lie in the interior of $T_n$, meaning that $T_n$ is acute-angled for any $n$ sufficiently large. On the other hand the shape of $T_n$ changes according to
$$(A,B,C)\to (\pi-2A,\pi-2B,\pi-2C) $$
and almost surely the map sending $x$ into $-2x\pmod{\pi}$ *is not* convergent.