Sequences of nested triangles
Let $ T_0 = \triangle A_0B_0C_0 $ and $ \lbrace T_n = \triangle A_nB_nC_n\rbrace_{n\geq 0} $ be the sequence of nested triangles where $ T_{n+1} $ is formed by taking the midpoints of the sides of $ T_n $. We can notice that $ \lbrace T_n\rbrace_{n\geq 0} $ converges to the centroid of $ T_0 $, as $ n \to \infty $. How can we prove this?
If we consider instead the intersections of the sides of $ T_n $ with the bisector of the opposite angle, we get that as $ n \to \infty $, $ T_n $ converges towards an equilateral triangle.
What happens if we now consider the orthogonal projection of the vertices of $ T_n $ on the opposite side and how do we prove the limiting point or shape?
There is a proof covered here for the case with the angle bisectors: http://dynamicmathematicslearning.com/Ismailescu-Jacobs2006-OnSequencesOfNestedTriangles.pdf
Can someone explain to me the proof using matrices and how can we prove the case with the centroid and the orthogonal projections?

For the midpoints of the sides, the proof is trivial once you note that all $T_n$ have the same centroid.

@Intelligentipauca how do I prove that?

HINT. A median of $T_k$ is also a median of $T_{k+1}$.

@Intelligentipauca all vertices of $T_k$ $k>=1$ lie on the medians of $A_0B_0C_0$ but I’m not sure how to write this

The case of orthogonal projection is considered in the paper you linked, on page 175 (pedal triangle).

@Intelligentipauca it doesn’t give a proof

See their ref. [12]: https://dair.dias.ie/id/eprint/866/1/DIAS-STP-83-16.pdf

See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3078774/255730

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Intelligentipauca so what happens in the case of the nth pedal triangle ?

Let $a_n,b_n,c_n$ the vertices of the $n$th triangle (think to them as complex numbers).
One can express the vertices of the
$n+1$th triangle in the following matrix-vector way :
$$\underbrace{\pmatrix{a_{n+1}\\b_{n+1}\\c_{n+1}}}_{V_{n+1}}=\underbrace{\pmatrix{0&\tfrac12&\tfrac12\\ \tfrac12&0&\tfrac12\\ \tfrac12&\tfrac12&0}}_M\underbrace{\pmatrix{a_{n}\\b_{n}\\c_{n}}}_{V_n}$$
From which we deduce :
$$V_n=M^nV_0$$
Diagonalization of $M$ shows that
$$M^n \to \tfrac13\pmatrix{1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1} \tag{1}$$
when $n \to \infty$ (see proof below).
As a consequence, using (1), we get the fact that ultimately, the three entries of $V_n$ converge towards $\frac13(a_0+b_0+c_0)$ which is the centroid of the initial triangle.
Remarks :

This technique can look sophisticated in this case, but it is important to have met it because it can be useful in more complicated cases.

On page 172 of the document cited, it is the very same matrix which is used but applied not to a vector of points but to a vector of angles...


Proof of the diagonalisation :
$M$ is diagonalizable with eigenvalues

$+1$ (simple), associated with unit eigenvector $V_1=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\pmatrix{1\\1\\1}$

$-\tfrac12$ (double), associated with (unit) eigenvectors $V_2$ and $V_3$ that we do not detail (the presence of this eigenvalue $-\tfrac12$ shouldn't come as a surprise : it accounts for the fact that taking the mid-triangle is, in a natural way, a homothety with ratio $-\tfrac12$).


Therefore, the eigendecomposition of symmetric matrix $M$ (resp. $M^n$) can be written :
$$M=Q\Lambda Q^T=(1)\tfrac13 V_1V_1^T+(-\tfrac12)V_2V_2^T+(-\tfrac12)V_3V_3^T$$
$$ (resp.) \ M^n=Q\Lambda^n Q^T=\underbrace{(1)^n \tfrac13 V_1V_1^T}_{\text{the matrix in (1)}}+\underbrace{(-\tfrac12)^n V_2V_2^T+(-\tfrac12)^n V_3V_3^T}_{\text{tends to} \ 0}$$
where $Q:=[V_1|V_2|V_3]$.

This technique can be applied to the case with the bisectors, correct? Like in the article I have linked

I have improved my explanations for the eigendecompositions of $M$ and $M^n$

Indeed on page 172 of this document (that I hadn't seen), it is the very same matrix which is used but applied not to a vector of points but to a vector of angles...

Just to be sure : does your question about orthogonal projections deals with convergence to orthocenter ?

In this post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3078774/255730 it says that the sequence is not convergent for the nth pedal triangle

How did you get 1/sqrt(3) here  $V_1=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\pmatrix{1\1\1}$ and what does this notation mean :=[1|2|3] ?

If I had I taken plainly $V_1=\pmatrix{1\1\1}$, $|V_1|^2=1^2+1^2+1^2=3$ therefore $|V_1|=\sqrt{3}$ : But we want a unit vector : consequence, we have to divide it by its norm... About notation $Q:=[V_1|V_2|V_3]$ : it defines the matrix with columns $V_1,V_2,V_3$
